# Installing R 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, r

I'm trying to install R version 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 via:
`sudo apt-get install r-base=4.0.2` but I get

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.0.2' for 'r-base' was not found
```

although [it does exist](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/).

I then tried following the instructions [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/) which detail the instructions for installing the latest version of R:

```bsh
# update indices
apt update -qq
# install two helper packages we need
apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr
# import the signing key (by Michael Rutter) for these repo
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
# add the R 4.0 repo from CRAN -- adjust 'focal' to 'groovy' or 'bionic' as needed
add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
```

Then:

```bsh
apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
```

For the last step, I tried r-base=4.0.2 instead since I don't want the latest version but I again get the same problem

EDIT: Based on Henning's answer, I ran `apt policy r-base`, which gave me:

```bsh
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.0-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

So I then tried `sudo apt-get install r-base=4.0.2-1.2004.0` which gave me:

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but 4.1.0-1.2004.0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing `r-recommended` but I still got the same issue

Comment: You have probably sorted it out already, but since the answer is still pending, I feel I should share what actually helped me: https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu repositories for Focal [offer R 3.6.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r-base). Just because another version of a software exists, that doesn't automatically mean that somebody packaged that version for Ubuntu (or Debian, or Fedora, or...) and offers those packages in their repository ;)

As for the repository offered by r-project.org, you may want to check what exact versions are available there. You can do that with `apt policy r-base` (after you added the repository to your list of package sources, of course). At the end of the output, there should be something along the lines of

```
 Version table:
 *** 3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In those version designations, you not only find the version of the "base software" (in this case, the version of R), but also the version of the Debian package built from that software, and often the version of the Ubuntu packages built from the Debian packages.

In this example, the only available version of `r-base` is `3.6.3-2`. That basically means "R version 3.6.3, and version 2 of the Debian packages built from that". An example with information about the version of the Ubuntu packages would be `apache2-2.4.41-4ubuntu3.1` (version 2.4.41 of the Apache HTTP server, version 4 of the Debian package built from that, and version 3.1 of the Ubuntu package built based on the Debian package).

So, your version designation to use in `apt install` isn't just the version of R, but the full version of the package you want to install (provided that package is in any of the repositories your system "knows" about, of course).

Comment: See my edited question based on your answer

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer Packages can depend on other packages. `r-base-4.0.2-1.2004.0` needs `r-recommended-4.0.2-1.2004.0`, but something else (a package that is to be installed or that already is installed) demands `r-recommend-4.1.0-1.2004.0`. This brought `apt` into a situation it can't resolve itself. You may want to comb through the dependencies with `apt depends name-of-package` (what does this depend on?) and `apt rdepends name-of-package` (what does depend on this?). A good starting point would probably be `apt rdepends r-recommended`, and then go from there.